# How to remove br tags in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, ckeditor

How do I remove `<br>` tags from ckeditor? I am using standard feature of ck editor and code using in config file as given below

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
       config.autoParagraph = false; 
   config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;

    // stops automatic insertion of <p> on focus

    config.allowedContent = false; // don't filter my data

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CKEDITOR.config.disallowedContent`

[Docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf-section-automatic-mode-but-disallow-certain-tags%2Fproperties), [more docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disallowedContent) and [small demo](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html)

For example, this should work:

```
config.disallowedContent = 'br';
```

Hope it helps!

Edit: [Here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) is another good doc page with examples